# Is kafka upgradable from 0.11.0.1 to newer version in operation?

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running apache kafka 0.11.0.1 cluster. And we plan to upgrade to 0.11.0.2 without stopping service.

Is upgrading possible without data-loss or reproducing?

Our kafka cluster state:

- Multiple brokers, multiple producers, multiple consumers.
- Every topics spreads to multiple partition
- Every topics have at least 2 replicas and all of them are in-sync.

Upgrading steps we think:

1. Stop one 0.11.0.1 broker.
2. Start 0.11.0.2 on stopped node. (same server.properties)
3. Do 1 and 2 for all brokers

Basically out consumers are consistes of kafka-client 0.11.0.1 and spark DStream consumer.

Of cource we'll test. But you know, test can not gurantee that everything will be OK. Any information must be helpful. Please give me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Kafka can be upgraded without any downtime.

There is a pretty large section about upgrading in the Kafka docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

For a minor release upgrade like in your scenario (0.11.0.0 to 0.11.0.1) the steps you've described should just work. Upgrade each broker one by one and after each step wait for everything to get back in-sync.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is exactly what I want to clarify.